# How to create a dropmenu with dynamic width

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu"> 
<li id="home"><a href="index.php" title="Home" class="menu-item">Home</a></li> 
<li class="list"><a href="#" title="About Us" class="menu-item">About</a> 
    <ul class="sub home">
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li class="list"><a href="#" title="Support" class="menu-item">Support</a> 
    <ul class="sub home">
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li class="list"><a href="#" title="Donate" class="menu-item">Donate</a></li> 
<li class="list"><a href="#" title="Grants" class="menu-item">Grants</a> 
    <ul class="sub home">
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page">Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li class="list"><a href="#" title="Contact Us" class="menu-item">Contact</a></li>
```

I'm using JQuery to create the dropdown effect as follows:

```
$('.menu .sub').css('display', 'none');

$('.menu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.sub').hide().stop(true, true).animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 200
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.sub').show().stop(true, true).animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 200
    });
});
```

And the CSS is:

```
.menu {
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #3d393a;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.menu li.list{
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul.sub{
    text-transform: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #fafaf8;
    border-right:1px solid #e4e0d5; 
    border-left:1px solid #e4e0d5;  
    border-bottom:1px solid #e4e0d5;    
    color: #7e7a7a;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
}
.menu ul.sub li:hover{  
}
.menu ul.sub li{
    border-top: 1px dashed #7E7A7A;
    display: block;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
.menu ul.sub>:first-child{
    border-top: none;
}
```

I need the width of the sub items to be dynamic and change to the correct width for the text so that it doesn't scroll to two lines on longer page titles. I tried using `innerWidth` but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `white-space=nowrap` css, it forces text to be only in 1 line.

.nowrap{
  white-space: nowrap
}

And then apply `class="nowrap"`.

Take a look at this:
http://www.icelab.eu/en/blog/css-4/css-nowrap-equivalent-8.htm

Hope this helps. Cheers